# How to assert multi-line alert text using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please find my sample alert code:

```js
alert('passed properties:\n' + passString +  ' \n\n Failed Properties:\n' + failString );
```

My selenium code:

```java
Alert alert = null;
alert = driver.switchTo.alert();
Assert.assertEquals("passed properties:\n<passString> \n\n Failed Properties:\n <failString>",alert.getText());
```

Comment: Can you post your webdriver code?

Comment: first i'm trying to switch to alert, then get text of from that alert. Asserting it with actual message.  `Assert.assertEquals("passed properties:\n + <passString> +   \n\n Failed Properties:\n + <failString>", alert.getText());`   when i do this i get both actual and expected the same. still the assert fails

Comment: @vincebowdren please find my updated code

Comment: I recommend debugging by finding out exactly what alert.getText() is returning - then it should be more obvious to you how you need to match it.

Comment: i can see very much in debug mode that, both the expected and the actual shows the same but still cudn't assert it. Don't know how